# Alexa Web API for Games - Skill Manifest

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-web-api-for-games

I enabled Alexa Web API for Games under Interface on Alexa Skill.

When I get the Skill Manifest, I clearly see

```
{
    "type": "ALEXA_PRESENTATION_HTML"
}
```

But when I ran the Test in Simulator I don't see the below in Request

```
...
    "device": {
      "deviceId": "amzn1.ask.device.XXXX",
      "supportedInterfaces": {
        **"Alexa.Presentation.HTML": {
          "runtime": {
            "maxVersion": "1.0"
          }**
        }
      }
    },
```

Am I missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the simulator does not support Alexa.Presentation.HTML
You will get this request when you try your skill on an Echo show device or FireTv.

Comment: ouch ... this hurt